# Laravel how to validate on modal edit

Tags: laravel

I have a page that consists of 2 modals, a modal for the add data form and a modal for the edit form. For modal add form has successfully validated the input and if validation error will call back the modal. However, the problem is when I want to validate the second modal, which is the edit form.

Error shown as below:

```
PATCH http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/vendor/store/3 422 (Unprocessable Entity)
```

my route:

```
    Route::post('/admin/vendor/store', [AdminVendor::class, 'store'])->name('admin.vendorstore');
    Route::get('/admin/{id}/vendor', [AdminVendor::class, 'edit'])->name('admin.vendoredit');
    Route::patch('/admin/vendor/store/{id}', [AdminVendor::class, 'update'])->name('admin.vendorupdate');
```

my controller:

```
public function edit($id)
{

    $vendor = Vendor::find($id);
    return view('admin.vendor-edit', [
        'vendor' => $vendor,
    ]);
}

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $request->validate([
        'code' => "required",
        'name' => "required|unique:vendors,name",
        'email' => "required|email|unique:vendors,email",
        'phone' => "required|min:8",
        'address' => "required|max:300",
    ]);
    Vendor::where('id', $id)->update([
        'code' => $request->code,
        'name' => $request->name,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'phone' => $request->phone,
        'address' => $request->address,
    ]);
}
```

my ajax:

```
@if ($errors->any())
    $('#modalTambah').modal({
        show: true
    });


    @endif
    $('.btn-edit').on('click', function () {
        let id = $(this).data('id');
        $.ajax({
            url: `/admin/${id}/vendor`,
            method: "GET",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#modalEdit').find('.modal-body').html(data);
                $('#modalEdit').modal('show');
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        })
    });

    $('.btn-update').on('click', function () {
        let id = $('#formData').find('#vendor-id').val();
        let formEdit = $('#formData').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: `/admin/vendor/store/${id}`,
            method: "PATCH",
            data: formEdit,
            success: function () {
                $('#modalEdit').modal('hide');
                window.location.assign('vendor');
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        })
    })
```

my modal:

```
<form id="formData" action=""
  method="post" >
@csrf
@method('put')
<div class="modal-wrapper">
    <div class="modal-text">
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="hidden" value="{{$vendor->id}}" id="vendor-id">
                <label @error('code')  class="text-danger" @enderror >KODE
                    VENDOR</label>
                <input type="text" id="code" name="code"
                       class="form-control  @error('code')  is-invalid @enderror"
                       value="{{$vendor->code}}"/>
                @error('code')
                <span class="text-danger">{{$message}}</span>
                @enderror
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label @error('name')  class="text-danger" @enderror>NAMA
                    VENDOR</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name"
                       class="form-control @error('name')  is-invalid @enderror"
                       value="{{$vendor->name}}"/>
                @error('name')
                <span class="text-danger">{{$message}}</span>
                @enderror
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row mt-3">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label
                    @error('email')  class="text-danger" @enderror>EMAIL</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email"
                       class="form-control @error('email')  is-invalid @enderror"
                       value="{{$vendor->email}}"/>
                @error('email')
                <span class="text-danger">{{$message}}</span>
                @enderror
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label
                    @error('phone')  class="text-danger" @enderror>Phone</label>
                <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone"
                       class="form-control @error('phone')  is-invalid @enderror"
                       value="{{$vendor->phone}}"/>
                @error('phone')
                <span class="text-danger">{{$message}}</span>
                @enderror
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group mt-3">
            <label
                @error('address')  class="text-danger" @enderror>ALAMAT</label>
            <input type="text" name="address" id="address"
                   class="form-control @error('address')  is-invalid @enderror"
                   value="{{$vendor->address}}"/>
            @error('address')
            <span class="text-danger">{{$message}}</span>
            @enderror
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalTambah" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <section class="card card-primary   ">
                <header class="card-header">
                    <h2 class="card-title">INPUT DATA VENDOR</h2>
                </header>
                <form action="{{route('admin.vendorstore')}}" method="post">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="modal-wrapper">
                            <div class="modal-text">
                                <div class="form-row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <label @error('code')  class="text-danger" @enderror >KODE
                                            VENDOR</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="code"
                                               class="form-control  @error('code')  is-invalid @enderror"
                                               value="{{old('code')}}"/>
                                        @error('code')
                                        <span class="text-danger">{{$message}}</span>
                                        @enderror
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <label @error('name')  class="text-danger" @enderror>NAMA
                                            VENDOR</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="name"
                                               class="form-control @error('name')  is-invalid @enderror"
                                               value="{{old('name')}}"/>
                                        @error('name')
                                        <span class="text-danger">{{$message}}</span>
                                        @enderror
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-row mt-3">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <label @error('email')  class="text-danger" @enderror>EMAIL</label>
                                        <input type="email" name="email"
                                               class="form-control @error('email')  is-invalid @enderror"
                                               value="{{old('email')}}"/>
                                        @error('email')
                                        <span class="text-danger">{{$message}}</span>
                                        @enderror
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <label @error('phone')  class="text-danger" @enderror>Phone</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="phone"
                                               class="form-control @error('phone')  is-invalid @enderror"
                                               value="{{old('phone')}}"/>
                                        @error('phone')
                                        <span class="text-danger">{{$message}}</span>
                                        @enderror
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group mt-3">
                                    <label @error('address')  class="text-danger" @enderror>ALAMAT</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="address"
                                           class="form-control @error('address')  is-invalid @enderror"
                                           value="{{old('address')}}"/>
                                    @error('address')
                                    <span class="text-danger">{{$message}}</span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <footer class="card-footer">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary modal-confirm" id="testing">Confirm</button>
                                <button id="modal-cancel" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </footer>
                </form>

            </section>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END : MODAL TAMBAH-->
```

Comment: What is the problem when you want to validate the second modal?

Comment: @Rwd the error shown like this: PATCH http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/vendor/store/3 422 (Unprocessable Entity)

Comment: Ok, so one or more of your validation rules isn't passing.

Comment: This error means your validation was unsuccessful. Try `dd($request);` and compare with your validation rules.

Comment: Rwd so how to sent the validation message / error to form edit. I can validate the add modal but i cant do this to edit modal, since i used @if(errors->any())  $('#modalTambah').modal({
        show: true
    }); @endif

Comment: In `error: function (error) {` you can handle the 422 error instead of just logging it.

Comment: @PeterKrebs how to do that , i tried to add $('#modalEdit').modal('show'); for handled the error just like on add form modal. But this edit modal, was freezed when it error 422

Comment: Well do you get any error messages on the console? Check [jQuery.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/Jquery.ajax/) documentation to handle the error. It might be `fail()` instead?

Comment: Wait, why are you using `@if ($errors->any())` when you're submitting the forms via ajax? If you not handling the errors in your JS then it's probably worth looking at [Named error bags](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#named-error-bags).